# FreeBSD pkg_add dependencies too new

Tags: freebsd, package-management

I'm trying to install Bash on a FreeBSD 8.3 (pfSense 2.1.2) system as follows:

```
pkg_add -r http://ftp-archive.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD-Archive/old-releases/amd64/8.3-RELEASE/packages/Latest/bash.tbz
```

which is <del>failing with</del> **throwing warnings** that

```
pkg_add: warning: package 'bash-4.2.20' requires 'libiconv-1.13.1_2', but 'libiconv-1.14_1' is installed
pkg_add: warning: package 'bash-4.2.20' requires 'gettext-0.18.1.1', but 'gettext-0.18.3.1' is installed
```

I mentioned that it's a pfSense box but there's no Bash package available via the web frontend; is there an easy way forward or should I be looking into use a ports system?

**Edit: it turns out that this was a non-fatal warning, and `bash` successfully installed after all.**

(Not tagged with [pfsense](/questions/tagged/pfsense) as it's not a routing/firewall issue, but feel free to retag if this turns out to be pfsense-specific.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a nasty one. Basically, pfSense 2.1.2 ships with newer versions of libiconv and gettext than those defined as dependencies for the FreeBSD 8.3-RELEASE bash package. As I see it, you have a few options (in order of effort):

1. Install the FreeBSD static bash package (`bash-static`) - that should not have any dependencies on shared libraries so *should* install fine.
2. Use a third party package source. The [pfSense site](https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Installing_FreeBSD_Packages) suggests [this site](http://ftpmirror.your.org/pub/FreeBSD-Unofficial-Packages/83amd64-default/Latest/) as an option. Of course, this is a third party site, so you'll need to trust them. I see that their packages use libiconv 1.14.1 and gettext 0.18.1.1 so their bash package should Just Work.
3. Compile your own bash package on a FreeBSD 8.3 system, after updating its libiconv and gettext packages to match those on pfSense 2.1.2.

Comment: Turns out bash **did** install, but I'd also thought about using the statically linked version (so long as no vulnerabilities turn up in iconv or gettext before the box gets replaced I'll be fine).